# Understanding statement: F free of rank r $\Rightarrow$ F/F' free abelian of rank r

Tags: abstract-algebra, free-groups, group-presentation, free-abelian-group

I found the following exercise on the 12th page of [Presentations of Groups](https://books.google.lu/books?hl=pt-BR&lr=&id=RYeIcopMH-IC&oi=fnd&pg=PP9&dq=Presentations%20of%20groups%20%20D.L.%20Johnson%20%20Cambridge%20University%20Press,%201997%202nd&ots=H2Scnn59OG&sig=65v6ywJSsp6KwfREE_ALDhOuhjI&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Presentations%20of%20groups%20D.L.%20Johnson%20Cambridge%20University%20Press%2C%201997%202nd&f=false):

> 8. Let $F$ be free of rank $r$. Show that $F/F'$ is free abelian of rank $r$.

First of all, $F'$ is not defined. I'm assuming it stands for a general normal subgroup of $F$.

So, what seems very strange here is that $F$ is not supposed to be abelian, but if I prove that $F/F'$ has the same rank that $F$ has, then, $F/F'$ and $F$ are isomorphic, right? But how can a non-necessarily abelian group be isomorphic to an abelian one?

It seems that someone has already posted a question here related to this:
[Let free group, F and F/F' have same rank](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168265/let-free-group-f-and-f-f-have-same-rank).

But the answers don't address the issue I'm pointing out here.

Comment: This says that $F_r/[F_r,F_r]\cong \mathbb{Z}^r$, where $F_r$ denotes the free group of rank $r$, i.e., with $r$ generators. Of course, $F_r$ is *not* isomrophic to $\mathbb{Z}^r$ for $r>1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F'$ denotes the derived subgroup of $F$, which is just another name for the commutator subgroup $[F,F]$. Thus $F/F'$ is just the abelianization of $F$. This should help you understand the answers in the other thread, or alternatively the answers to the question [Abelianization of free group is the free abelian group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666155/abelianization-of-free-group-is-the-free-abelian-group).

Comment: Ok. I got it. On the other hand, it is still strange that this factor group is abelian and isomorphic to $F$. If two groups are isomorphic, they are both abelian or both non-abelian, right?

Comment: Yes, but $F/F'$ and $F$ are **not** isomorphic. The point is that $F$ is *free* of rank $r$ and $F/F'$ is *free abelian* of rank $r$. These are two different universal properties, so it doesn't imply that they must be isomorphic.

Comment: Ok, I see. The book didn't explicitly defined free abelian groups, just made a comment about that. And it now even comment about commutator subgroup. So I think this is why I get confused on that. Thank you for clarifying those points.